# How to redirect back to a dynamic page after deleting a record in Django

Tags: django

I have the following working code to delete a record from a table through the following url/view and template:

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('portfolio/<str:pk>/', views.portfolio, name="portfolio"),
    path('delete_identifier/<str:pk>/', views.deleteIdentifier, name="delete_identifier"),
]
```

**Models**

```
class Account(TimeStampMixin, models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Identifier(TimeStampMixin, models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

**View**

```
def portfolio(request, pk):
    portfolio = Account.objects.get(id=pk)
    identifiers = Identifier.objects.filter(account=pk)

    context = {"portfolio": portfolio, "identifiers": identifiers}
    return render(request, 'portfolio.html', context)


def deleteIdentifier(request, pk):
    identifier = Identifier.objects.get(id=pk)
    identifier.delete()
    return redirect('portfolio')
```

**template (portfolio.html)**

```
<table class="table table-sm">

    {% for item in identifiers %}

    <tr>
        <td>{{item.code}}</td>

        <td style="width:10px;"><a class="delete_btn" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" href="{% url 'delete_identifier' item.id %}">Delete</a></td>

    </tr>
    
    {% endfor %}

</table>
```

However the issue is with my redirect in the view - I'm basically trying to go back to the same page where I'm deleting the record from 'portfolio' but am unable to. Instead I get redirected to: 127.0.0.1:8000/delete_identifier/882/ with  the following error on on page:

DoesNotExist at /delete_identifier/882/

Identifier matching query does not exist.

My expectation is to be redirected back to the original page of: 127.0.0.1:8000/portfolio/205/ where I started from.

I'd greatly appreciate some help in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: could you post models.py code

Comment: @B.Anup I've now added Models to above. Thanks

Comment: Also just to elaborate further, the view portfolio works fine the only issue is with deleteIdentifier view specifically on this line: `return redirect('portfolio')`

Comment: url "portfolio" accepts arguments, try passing some valid argument after deleting identifier.
redirect('portfolio', pk="205")

Comment: @B.Anup Thank you very much this worked - I knew it was about pk but didn't know where to put and tested manually as per your advice harcoding the number and worked and then changed to the following: `return redirect('portfolio',  pk=identifier.account_id)` which now works dynamically. This is now resolved Thanks again!